# Is it possible to run multiple threads simultaneously on a same core?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am calling a Flask server(running with 64 gunicorn workers) via http with ThreadPoolExecutor to test execution time.

Both(test script and Flask server) are running on the same host. Inside the Flask endpoint, there is a DB(Postgres) call.

Machine stats (11 cores, 16 GB ram)

**Test script:**

```
class StressTest():

    def __init__(self, max_workers):
        self.__max_workers = max_workers

    def __async_test(self, x=range(1000)):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.__max_workers) as executor:
            futures = [
                executor.submit(
                    self.__test,
                    n=n
                )
                for n in x
            ]

        for future in futures:
            try:
                future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception(e)

    def __test(self, n):
        # Rest call


    def run(self):
        start_time = datetime.now()
        self.__async_test()

        duration = datetime.now() - start_time
        self.logger.info(f"duration for the process is {duration.total_seconds()} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    StressTest(1).run()
    StressTest(2).run()
    StressTest(4).run()
    .......
```

**Results as follows:**

| No of threads | Execution time (s) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 8 | 8.5 |
| 16 | 8 |
| 32 | 7.5 |
| 64 | 7.5 |

**My question is why execution time is saturating after 8 threads?** Isn't it possible to run multiple threads at the same time in a given core?

Any given time, only 11 threads are running (via htop) during the test.

Please let me know if you want additional information about my test. Thank you!

Comment: IDK how to give a definitive answer, but the shape of your "No of threads" vs. "Execution time(s)" table makes me wonder if maybe you are running up against [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: 11 cores is a bit unusual, but I can imagine a Virtual Machine with 11 cores assigned. I'm slightly surprised by this question, though. The definition of a _CPU core_ is pretty much 'the part of a CPU which runs a single thread". That's so much part of the definition that we have special names for the exception. E.g. Intel calls it HyperThreading. (2 threads/core). But in those cases, we talk about virtual cores that execute only one thread. And in VM environments, we typically consider these virtual cores.

Answer (score 1):

> It (ThreadPoolExecutor) utilizes at most 32 CPU cores for CPU bound tasks which release the GIL

It's that latter condition which should worry you. "GIL" is the Global Interpreter Lock. Your Python runtime has only one such lock, that's why it is called "Global". And it's used for pretty much anything that works with memory. Even a simple `a=b` can require the GIL. Statements like these are therefore not faster if more cores are available - there simply aren't more locks.

However, I/O operations are designed so that they do not need the GIL while the OS is working on the operation. In this case, multiple cores could help a bit - but here the OS typically is waiting on other hardware, not the CPU.

Postgres *can* use multiple threads, so you can have multiple threads execute multiple queries. This would likely give a speed-up for that part of the processing. As noted in the comments, Amdahl's Law tells you that a program with mixed multi-threaded and single-threaded parts will be limited by its single-threaded parts if enough cores are available. And in Python, the GIL behaves as that single-threaded part.

Comment: Flask side I am using a connection pool (SqlAlchemy). To test, I just called a dummy endpoint without DB call and execution times are not changing. I am trying to understand how can I speed up the execution time for I/O operations(http, file operation, s3) on a given list.

Comment: @Janukasamaranyake: Threading is useful to speed up computers which have idle cores. It looks like you can keep all 11 cores busy with a moderate amount of threads. That's generally a _good_ thing. It means you can expect a speedup by getting more hardware. Hardware is generally cheaper than (good) programmers.

Answer (score 1):

TL/DR: Regardless a programming language used, given core can execute only 1 thread for a given moment of time.

More details:
While we say "thread" we can mean CPU-level execution entity (and the answer is above, period), or we can actually talk about so called "tasks", or "async execution", or "futures", whatever. All that terms are about describing a next-level abstraction over a thread via specifying logical steps to get the business be done, not about direct utilization of CPU capabilities. However, actual execution of that abstraction is still performed via CPU thread(s). And that returns us back to the very first disclaimer: given core can execute only 1 thread for a given moment of time.

Comment: A so-called ["Hyper-threaded" CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) can execute instructions on behalf of two threads at the same time without any intervention from the operating system. Depending on details of the CPU design, and depending on the details of the code that it is executing, it may be able to do the same work as anywhere between one and two non-hyper-threaded CPUs.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that things are about two cores that share some CPU building blocks (that can be used as an advantage under some scenarios) so you can think about them as Siamese tweens. So, they're two cores, not a single one.

Comment: I was taught that if they "share some CPU building blocks" then they aren't distinct "cores." Some people call them "_logical_ cores," or "_logical_ CPUs." And, some people call them "hardware threads." What I was taught is that each "core" has its own L1 cache and memory interface. But, y'know, language does change over time, so maybe my learning is out-dated.